# XML-RPC struct to C# class with dynamic named structs

Tags: c#, struct, xml-rpc

I am trying to map an XML-RPC struct into a C# class.  I am using XmlRpcLight from github.  Below is the XML-RPC being passed:

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1""?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>namespace.method</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member>
                        <name>OrderID</name>
                        <value>
                            <int>1</int>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                    <member>
                        <name>OrderItems</name>
                        <value>
                            <struct>
                                <member>
                                    <name>0</name>
                                    <value>
                                        <struct>
                                            <member>
                                                <name>ItemID</name>
                                                <value>
                                                    <string>12345</string>
                                                </value>
                                            </member>
                                        </struct>
                                    </value>
                                </member>
                                <member>
                                    <name>1</name>
                                    <value>
                                        <struct>
                                            <member>
                                                <name>ItemID</name>
                                                <value>
                                                    <string>23456</string>
                                                </value>
                                            </member>
                                        </struct>
                                    </value>
                                </member>
                            </struct>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                </struct>
            </value>
        </param>
   </params>
</methodCall>
```

The classes i am using to try and map this is as follows:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public string ItemID;
}

public class OrderItems 
{
   public OrderItem[] OrderItem;
}

public class OrderData
{
    public int OrderID;
    public OrderItems OrderItems;
}
```

The error message i am receiving back is as follows.

request contains struct value with missing non-optional member: OrderItem [request : parameter 2 : struct mapped to type OrderData : member OrderItems mapped to type OrderItems : struct mapped to type OrderItems]

I can't work out how to map this because the Order Item names are a dynamic number.  I have tried arrays, arrays of arrays but nothing seems to let it go through.  The only way i have got it to work is to use an XmlRpcStruct type in place of a custom class for "OrderItems".  While this works it isn't the result i want.

Can anybody please help me understand how these XMl-RPC types can be mapped to C#?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: There is also an xml-rpc wrapper for .Net: http://xml-rpc.net/

Comment: Yeah read through that, it talks about arrays but not array of structs... that section is particularly small - very frustrating!

Comment: What about the comment from SO which said just use the dynamic type?

Comment: Dynamic type is a good suggestion, but it maps to an XmlRpcStruct, which is a key value pair - ultimately i will have to go with it if all else fails, but i wanted to understand what that struct looks like in c# and use it as legitimate classes.

Comment: Try again mister, I forgot to undo my previous trials.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Paste-Special to generate your classes for you?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14700981/112397

---

The c# generated off your xml is horrible, but I can kinda see what its trying to do, have you tried something like this?

EDIT: I think you might be missing a level of inheritance.

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemID;
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public Item[] Items;
}

public class OrderItems 
{
   public OrderItem[] OrderItem;
}

public class OrderData
{
    public int OrderID;
    public OrderItems OrderItems;
}
```

Your array of arrays comment struck me as I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9960559/112397), thought I would generate that code myself and see if I saw anything like that.

Comment: I didnt know that existed - its very cool!  However sadly doesn't quite work to solve the issue.

Comment: yeah i have tried all sorts to get it going, it always responds with the same or similar error message.  And yeah, its a stretch to call it XML!  Sadly XML-RPC is forced upon me, give me Soap or WCF any day please!

Comment: just spotted your link in your edit, yeah thats where i got the idea to nest the arrays and try that.  The issue is the Name being different (array index) in each OrderItem.  I think its struggling because the XmlRpcLight framework is name matching... the response in your link is from Charles Cook who wrote XMLRPC.Net, the XmlRpcLight is derived from this code but a lighter framework.  Everything is pointing to the fact that it currently isnt possible.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions... however using an array at the orderdata level produces this error:  request contains struct value where array expected (as type OrderItems[]) [request : parameter 2 : struct mapped to type Order : member OrderItems mapped to type OrderItems[]]